# Seeking Razor View C# Stimulsoft.StiMvcViewer converted to VB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, view, stimulsoft

I'm familiar with the VB language of "New With {.xyz = "abc"}), but this one has me stumped.
The C# razor code is;

```
@Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(new StiMvcViewerOptions()
{
Actions = 
{
GetReportSnapshot = "GetReportSnapshotITypedList",
ViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent"
}
})
```

So, how is this represented in VB razor code? Specifically, I'm not sure how to address the "Actions = " and the sub-functions "GetReportSnapshot" etc...
Thanks!

Comment: ran it through telerik c' to vb.net converter - Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(New StiMvcViewerOptions() With { Key .Actions = {Key .GetReportSnapshot = "GetReportSnapshotITypedList", Key .ViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent"}})

Comment: not sure if it's valid code hough - I'm not at my vb computer.

Comment: Thanks to your reply, I'm getting closer, but still not there yet:@Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(New StiMvcViewerOptions() With { _
        .Actions = {.Actions.GetReportSnapshot() = "GetReportSnapshotITypedList", _
                  .Actions.ViewerEvent() = "ViewerEvent"
            }})

Comment: @Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(New StiMvcViewerOptions() With { _
        .Actions = {.Actions.GetReportSnapshot="GetReportSnapshotITypedList", .Actions.ViewerEvent="ViewerEvent"}}) gives me the error of "Value of type '1-dimensional array of boolean cannot be converted to ...actionoptions

Comment: How do I add an image to my post? I captured the Intellisense prompts, which may help decipher what to do next.  So how can I post an image?

Comment: Yep you can add an image - in the toolbar at the top of the bit where you're typing your question, you have a `B` for bold text, an `I` for italic text etc.  The sixth one along is a rectangle with a stylized mountain and sun inside the it. Click that and you can drag and drop your picture into there. In the text box, at the current cursor position you'll get some highlighted text where you can add a description of the image. Overwrite the highlighted text and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Imports Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc
@Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

@code
    Dim opt As New StiMvcViewerOptions()
    opt.Actions.GetReportSnapshot = "GetReportSnapshotITypedList"
    opt.Actions.ViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent"
    Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(opt)
End Code
```

Since my question was just on syntax, I believe I can just do the above. Sometimes I wonder why we concentrate so much on using convoluted syntax, when a simple Dim statement does this trick.

Now, if only I can get the Stimulsoft .mrt report to show up...